# Perl: Read email and use message content as stdin for an excel update

Tags: excel, perl, email

I am looking for some help with starting a Perl script. I'm relatively inexperienced with Perl so help would be appreciated :)

Basically, want to start a project to write a script that helps keep up to date with hours I have been working. Basically I would like the script to E-mail (automated using cron) me reminding me to send my hours each day, then I send an e-mail back with the message as something like 
"03/02/14    7.30    18.30" 
The script will then read the data and update an excel spreadsheet keeping a log of hours.

I know how to do everything except having the script read an e-mail. I have been doing research into MIME::* MAIL::* but I'm not entirely sure which package would be the best and how to actually go about it.

Comment: Mail access by [IMAP](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Net-IMAP-Simple-1.2204/Simple.pod) or [local mailbox](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/Mail-Box-2.106/lib/Mail/Box/Parser/Perl.pod)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mpapec suggested you could read email using IMAP or a local mailbox on a linux box.

In windows you could use OLE and read emails in an outlook: [Perl: Win32::OLE and Microsoft Outlook - Iterating through email attachments efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654941/perl-win32ole-and-microsoft-outlook-iterating-through-email-attachments-eff)

You could read emails on exchange in this way: http://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Folder::Exchange

If I were you I would use IMAP to access emails. It is platform independent and not too hard to use (I used it in the past and it was reliable).

http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Client

```
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(

    server => 'mail.you.com',
    user   => 'USERID',
    pass   => 'PASSWORD');

# select folder
$imap->select('INBOX');
#newest first
my $messages = $imap->search({
    FROM    => 'you',
    SUBJECT => 'your email subjet',
}, [ '^DATE' ]);   
# fetch full message     (newest)
my $data = $imap->get_rfc822_body($messages->[0]);
#process    
store_data_in_excel($data);
#move to archive
$imap->copy([$messages->[0]], 'Archive');
$imap->add_flags(\@msg_ids, '\\Deleted');
$imap->expunge;
```

Comment: Thanks for this user1126070 :)