# download attachments from ms outlook using perl

Tags: perl, outlook

I am assigned to download attachments from ms outlook using perl with the mail subject as `Net file`. Since i am new to perl i am confused how to proceed. This is the code with which i have to proceed with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
my $outlook;
eval {$outlook = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')};
die "Outlook not installed" if $@;
unless (defined $outlook) {
    $outlook = Win32::OLE->new('Outlook.Application','Quit') 
               or die "Unable to start Outlook";
}

$outlook->{visible} = 0;

my $dir = "F:\\OL\\";      #destination  directory
$dir =~ s/\//\\/g;

#get the Inbox folder
my $namespace = $outlook->GetNamespace("MAPI");
```

Can some one please help me with the remaining part of the code.

Comment: no error i dont no how to proceed, can you please help me with the remaining code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a lot of info form this: [Perl: Win32::OLE and Microsoft Outlook - Iterating through email attachments efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654941/perl-win32ole-and-microsoft-outlook-iterating-through-email-attachments-eff) or from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=700307

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

my $Folder = $NameSpace->GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);

foreach my $msg (reverse in($Folder->{items}))
    print "Subject: ",$msg->{'Subject'},"\n";
    next if $msg->{'Subject'} !~ m!Net file!i;
    foreach my $atch (reverse in($msg->{Attachments}))
        if($atch->{FileName} =~ m/.xls$/i){
            if($atch->{FileName} =~ /Name of attachment1/i){
                print "found ".$atch->{FileName}."\n";
            }

       }
   }
}
```

or you could use [Mail::Outlook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::Outlook)

Comment: it gives an error as `$atch requires explicit package name`

Comment: look in the first url provided ... the sample code there holds the missing line/loop <code>    foreach my $atch (in $msg->{Attachments}){</code>

Comment: but this will work fine if the attachment is of `.xls` format. I need to download attachments of various formats with that particular subject name. @lexu

Comment: @Programmer: look at the line **if($atch->{FileName} =~ m/.xls$/i){** See the xls? that's what selects the extension for excel ..